# ImageView within RelativeLayout is not matching parent

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, imageview

So, I'm trying to view a camera preview as a background with an imageview on top of it. Check this [question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388572/how-to-set-camera-view-as-background-with-views-over-it), that I've asked, to get a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish. However, instead of using a FrameLayout, I found it easier to use a RelativeLayout (for the reason of placing views where I want on the screen). The problem is that I can't get the imageview (over the surface view) to take up the whole screen. No matter how I re-size the image it still displays in the center without filling the screen.

So, my question is, how would I make the imageview fill the entire screen over the surface view? Perhaps, I am making a simple mistake but if that is the case please point it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Here's the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/relative" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:src="@drawable/background" >
</ImageView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Scan"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="Scan" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="Search" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/importing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Import"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="Import" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code where I place the views (bring to front so they are visible over the surface view):

```
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    relative.addView(mPreview);
    layout.bringToFront();
    scan.bringToFront();
    search.bringToFront();
    friendImport.bringToFront();
```

**EDIT:**
Here's an example image of what I'm talking about (I am trying to get the white transparent image to cover the whole screen):

[image: image not displaying full screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting for a while, I seem to have found a solution to my problem. My image was showing up similar to this picture:

[image: 9 patch description]

Which is weird, because this is how a 9-patch image works and I did not declare my image as a 9-patch. But even when I called match_parent (or even fill_parent) it only filled to the fill area like in the image I posted.

So, with lots of trial and error, I took away any border that was on the image and took all the blur effects off. The image was, for some reason, a dramatically smaller file size. Then, I tried to place this as the background and... success!

I'm not too sure as to why it did not work to begin with, but, I have a theory that, perhaps, because there was a 1px border on the image it saved it as a 9-patch PNG instead of a normal PNG file. Or maybe it was due to the blur effect that was on the image. I'm not too sure, but, I do know that once I took off the blur effects and removed the border it did work.

I hope this is useful for anyone who might be faced with a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct that you want to stretch android:id="@+id/image" into your entire layout?
First check in layout view that the ImageView takes entire space as it is supposed to. 
If so, then add the proper scaling type to your ImageView attribute list:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Or as an alternative, apply the image resource not as "src" but as "background":

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I would like android:id="@+id/image" to be the entire screen size. Unfortunately, I have tried both methods you have stated and no luck. I also use the attributes "fill_parent" for the height and width, yet, this seems to do nothing. If you have any other advice feel free to state it, I'm lost here